# Appium unable to install plugin

Tags: appium

I was going to study mobile automation using Appium. But for some reasons, I am unable to open the application. I keep getting the "No plugins have been installed". Use the "appium plugin" command to install the one(s) you want to use.", but whenever I try the appium plugin, it was not working

[image]

I have tried the appium plugin command already